# (MATLAB) ALL integer positive solutions for a linear equation

Tags: matlab, math, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I want to generate a list, named `listt`, that contains all possible positive integers that sum into a specific number `d`. For example, I am looking at the list of all the possible positive integer values for `x's` such that `x1 + x2 + ... + xk = d`.

In this case, the row size of `listt` should be `(d+k-1) choose (k-1)`.

I already have the `MATLAB code` for doing that (see below), but the main problem is that this code allows repetitive rows in `listt`. **I need help in order to change this code suth that there are no repetitive rows in `listt`.**

```
k = 2;
d = 2;
m = nchoosek(d+k-1, k-1);

% generate non-negative integer random (m x k) array row-sum to d 
ss=rand(m,d+k-1);
[~,r] = maxk(ss,k-1,2);
z = zeros(m,1);
listt = diff([z, sort(r,2), (d+k)+z],1,2)-1;
```

Let's say `d=5` and `k=2`.
Assume I get the following listt:

```
 1     4
 2     3
 0     5
 5     0
 5     0
 0     5
```

So as you can see, the row (5,0) and row (0,5) are repeated two times each. I want to get unique rows.

**More precisely, for `d=5` and `k=2`, what do I want to get exactly is the following all 6 possibilities:**

```
 1     4
 2     3
 0     5
 5     0
 4     1
 3     2
```

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: Is applying `listtt = unique(listt, 'rows');`at the end fine for you? Or do you need to avoid generating repeated rows in the first place?

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for the comment. This will not be enough because I essentially need all the possibilities that each sum to d.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the exact desired result for a given case such as `d=5`, `k=2`?

Comment: @LuisMendo I updated my question to include an example of d=5 and k=2. I need all the possibilities. Here's we have 6 possibilities that each sum to 5. If I apply unique, so I will lose some possibilities.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Thanks for your time. BTW for d=6 and k=3, the total number of possibilities is 26 and not 7 as in your update!

Comment: I just realized there is a previous question about this problem: integer partitions. (I should have remembered because I answered there, but it was long ago). Mark Dickinson's answer there uses the same approach as mine here. I'm marking this question as a duplicate for the benefit of future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `d` denote the desired sum and `k` the number of components.

```
d = 5; % desired sum
k = 2; % desired number of components
b = nchoosek(1:d+k-1, k-1);
t = [ones(size(b,1),1) b+1 repmat(d+k+1, size(b,1),1)];
result = diff(t, [], 2)-1;
```

The code works by representing each solution as a row vector containing `k+1` increasing integers starting at `1` and ending at `d+k+1` (matrix `t` in the code). The `k-1` inner integers are generated using `nchoosek`. The actual solution is then obtained from the `k` consecutive differences between those integers.

For example, the matrix `t` for inputs `d=5` and `k=2` is

```
1     2     8
1     3     8
1     4     8
1     5     8
1     6     8
1     7     8
```

which gives the result

```
0     5
1     4
2     3
3     2
4     1
5     0
```

Comment: Awesome Luis, thanks a lot. It works fine for me. BTW your previous code worked fine too. What is the main difference between the old one and this one? Both of them work fine I think no?

Comment: The old one had a long unnecessary detour. In the old version, note that `ii` was `b.'+1` with the two extra initial and ending rows attached. This is solved in the current version, which is cleaner

Comment: Okay great! Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it - you really wanted not partition, but [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) !

Ok, there is good MATLAB package exactly for that: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27110-restricted-integer-composition

Example using it:

```
d=6;
k=3;

jdoric( d,k,k,0,d );
```

will print

```
   1   0   5
   1   1   4
   1   2   3
   1   3   2
   1   4   1
   1   5   0
   2   0   4
   2   1   3
   2   2   2
   2   3   1
   2   4   0
   3   0   3
   3   1   2
   3   2   1
   3   3   0
   4   0   2
   4   1   1
   4   2   0
   5   0   1
   5   1   0
   2   0   4
   2   1   3
   2   2   2
   2   3   1
   2   4   0
   3   0   3
   3   1   2
   3   2   1
   3   3   0
   4   0   2
   4   1   1
   4   2   0
   5   0   1
   5   1   0
   3   0   3
   3   1   2
   3   2   1
   3   3   0
   4   0   2
   4   1   1
   4   2   0
   5   0   1
   5   1   0
   4   0   2
   4   1   1
   4   2   0
   5   0   1
   5   1   0
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this result! Much appreciated.

Comment: This produces repeated rows, and thus it doesn't seem to be what the OP wants

Answer (score 0):

This is called [partition of an integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). It is exponential in n, and there is a good implementation in Python, [https://ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/PADS/IntegerPartitions.py](https://ics.uci.edu/%7Eeppstein/PADS/IntegerPartitions.py).

I found MATLAB implementation, but never used it: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36437-integer-partition-generator

> In this case, the row size of listt should be (d+k-1) choose (k-1)

not sure how you got this result, partition function p(n) is about

p(n) ~ 1/(4 n sqrt(3)) exp(pi sqrt(2 n / 3))

UPDATE

If you need only partitions which have specific length, then you could run partition algorithm for a given **d** till first output exceeding **k** numbers. Didn't try MATLAB algorithm, but Python and other I tried were all going from shortest partition to longest one. Easy to check for specific length and break.

UPDATE II

Downloaded MATLAB package and ran it using Octave. It has interface you're asking for, e.g.

```
d = 6;
k = 3;

s=intpartgen(d,k);
```

produced

```
6  0  0
5  1  0
4  1  1
3  2  1
4  2  0
2  2  2
3  3  0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My task that I want to achieve is a part from the "multinomial expansion". I don't think in my case it is related to partition of an integer. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Christina "all possible positive integers that sum into a specific number d" sounds exactly like partition of an integer

Comment: @Christina could you provide an example for say d=5 ?

Comment: @Christina Ok, so you run partition function and stop when length of a sum exceeds your k. Updating answer.

Comment: Okay thanks! I updated my answer so now it is more clear.

Comment: Sorry to point this out (and to downvote) as in your other answer, but again the result you provide does not match what the OP wants, as she previously commented